# Custom Menu ceated in Add-In works once then throw a RT5 error on subsequent attempts

Tags: excel, add-in, vba

I have created an AddIn that utilizes an extensive menu system to call code based on the worksheet name the user is working in. Some of these worksheets are in different workbooks. All of the individual subs work, but I am having difficulty in figuring out why the menu (a button in the Ribbon triggers the menu code) only works once, then gives me a

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

The button triggers this code to run:

```
Sub CreateMasterMenu()

'
    Select Case ActiveSheet.name
        Case "BCM Hourly Comparison an": Call Extract_Initial_Save
        Case "Daily Impacts Verification Step": Call Verification_Initial_Save
        Case "Extract": Call Extract_Menu
        Case "Swivel": Call Swivel_Menu
        Case "Disputed": Call Disputed_Menu
        Case "Verification": Call Verification_Menu
        Case Else: MsgBox "There are no menu options available for this worksheet."
    End Select

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(Menuname).ShowPopup
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

This will call a popup menu based on the name of the active worksheet. When I first open the workbook and make a choice, it works as expected. But when I click on the button a second time to make another choice, I receive the RT error.

```
Sub Swivel_Menu()

'
    Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup

    With Application.CommandBars.Add(name:=Menuname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
         MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True) 'This is where the debugger says the error is

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Hide Columns"
            .FaceId = 1649
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & "Swivel_Hide_Columns"
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Highlight & Copy Disputed"
            .FaceId = 3881
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & "Swivel_HandC_Disputed"
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Swivel Sheet Sort"
            .FaceId = 706
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & "Swivel_Sheet_sort"
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Unhide Columns"
            .FaceId = 1650
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & "Swivel_Unhide_Columns"
        End With

        Set MenuItem = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
        With MenuItem
            .Caption = "Swivel Tools"

            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Remove Duplicates"
                .FaceId = 2165
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & "Swivel_Remove_Duplicates"
            End With
            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Copy To Validate"
                .FaceId = 731
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & "Swivel_Copy_To_Validate"
            End With
            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Not Available"
                .FaceId = 463
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & "Menu_Construct_Msg"
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I had this code running from a workbook and did not have this issue. It is pretty much copied into the add-in (with extra menu options added), but the code is the same.

Am I getting this error because I am running it from an add-in as opposed to running it from the workbook as before?

Comment: You don't appear to delete any existing commandbar by that name before trying to add a new one.

Comment: @Rory Just as you posted, I made the same discovery. +1 for being quick! Thanks for the help.